# Using Camel Bean validator Component

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am getting an exception while using Camel Bean Validator. The exception is `No component found with scheme: bean-validator`
And i have these dependencies in my POM

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-bean-validator</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And i am using Bean Validator component as below

```
from("direct:XXX").process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        Car car = new Car();
        //car.setVehicleId(1);
        car.setName("Swift");
        car.setCompany("Maruti");

        exchange.getIn().setBody(car);              
    }
}).to("bean-validator://x").process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange arg0) throws Exception {
        LOG.debug("Bean Validation is Success");
    }
});
```

But when i am deploying the generated war into the Wildfly, am getting the exception `No component found with scheme: bean-validator`. To my surprise the code is working fine in standalone application.
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you initializing the camel context? Do you initialize the `HibernateValidationProviderResolver` manually? See http://camel.apache.org/bean-validation.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you define the scope as provided, which means the JAR is supposely already part of the server. You most often only use provided scope for API JARs such as the servlet api, etc.

So change this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-bean-validator</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version> 
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

To

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-bean-validator</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.2</version> 
</dependency>
```